# Find the longest substring in alphabetical order

Tags: python

I have this code that I found on another topic, but it sorts the substring by contiguous characters and not by alphabetical order. How do I correct it for alphabetical order? It prints out `lk`, and I want to print `ccl`. Thanks

ps: I'm a beginner in python

```
s = 'cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar'
from itertools import count

def long_alphabet(input_string):
    maxsubstr = input_string[0:0] # empty slice (to accept subclasses of str)
    for start in range(len(input_string)): # O(n)
        for end in count(start + len(maxsubstr) + 1): # O(m)
            substr = input_string[start:end] # O(m)
            if len(set(substr)) != (end - start): # found duplicates or EOS
                break
            if (ord(max(sorted(substr))) - ord(min(sorted(substr))) + 1) == len(substr):
                maxsubstr = substr
    return maxsubstr

bla = (long_alphabet(s))
print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is: %s" %bla
```

Comment: What does "longest in alphabetical order" mean?  How can the one value you print be in ANY order?

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers : For example, if s = 'tjkocgygiwc' the longest substring in alphabetic order is 'jko', i don't now how to do to find this 'jko', the program finds jk. With 'wvcdcgykkaypy' it finds 'wv' and not 'cgy'

Comment: [Simple and easy to understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618533/finding-longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order/39658014#39658014) Explained clearly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
        if len(set(substr)) != (end - start): # found duplicates or EOS
            break
        if (ord(max(sorted(substr))) - ord(min(sorted(substr))) + 1) == len(substr):
```

to this:

```
        if len(substr) != (end - start): # found duplicates or EOS
            break
        if sorted(substr) == list(substr):
```

That will display `ccl` for your example input string.  The code is simpler because you're trying to solve a simpler problem :-)

Answer (score 19):

```
s = 'cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar'
r = ''
c = ''
for char in s:
    if (c == ''):
        c = char
    elif (c[-1] <= char):
        c += char
    elif (c[-1] > char):
        if (len(r) < len(c)):
            r = c
            c = char
        else:
            c = char
if (len(c) > len(r)):
    r = c
print(r)
```

Comment: Some comments to explain it or meaningful names for variables would help out readability here

Answer (score 4):

You can improve your algorithm by noticing that the string can be broken into runs of ordered substrings of maximal length.  Any ordered substring must be contained in one of these runs

This allows you to just iterate once through the string O(n)

```
def longest_substring(string):
    curr, subs = '', ''
    for char in string:
        if not curr or char >= curr[-1]:
            curr += char
        else:
            curr, subs = '', max(curr, subs, key=len)
    return max(curr, subs, key=len)
```

Comment: need to set `subs = x` instead of `''` in `else`
otherwise first char of max sequence could be missed, example:
sequence is: `azcbobobegghakl`
result is: `eggh`

Answer (score 3):

```
s = 'cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar'
longest = ""
max =""

for i in range(len(s) -1):
    if(s[i] <= s[i+1] ):
       longest = longest + s[i]
       if(i==len(s) -2):
           longest = longest + s[i+1]
    else:
        longest  = longest + s[i]        
        if(len(longest) > len(max)):
            max = longest
        longest = ""        

if(len(s) == 1):
    longest = s


if(len(longest) > len(max)):
    print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + longest)
else:
    print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + max)
```

Answer (score 2):

In a recursive way, you can import **count** from *itertools*

Or define a same method:

```
def loops( I=0, S=1 ):
    n = I
    while True:
        yield n
        n += S
```

With this method, you can obtain the value of an endpoint, when you create any substring in your anallitic process.

Now looks the anallize method (based on *[spacegame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2921962/spacegame)* issue and Mr. *[Tim Petters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705542/tim-peters)* suggestion)

```
def anallize(inStr):
    # empty slice (maxStr) to implement
    # str native methods
    # in the anallize search execution
    maxStr = inStr[0:0]
    # loop to read the input string (inStr)
    for i in range(len(inStr)):
        # loop to sort and compare each new substring
        # the loop uses the loops method of past
        # I = sum of: 
        #     (i) current read index
        #     (len(maxStr)) current answer length
        #     and 1
        for o in loops(i + len(maxStr) + 1):
            # create a new substring (newStr)
            # the substring is taked:
            # from: index of read loop (i)
            # to:   index of sort and compare loop (o)
            newStr = inStr[i:o]

            if len(newStr) != (o - i):# detect and found duplicates
                break
            if sorted(newStr) == list(newStr):# compares if sorted string is equal to listed string
                # if success, the substring of sort and compare is assigned as answer
                maxStr = newStr
    # return the string recovered as longest substring
    return maxStr
```

Finally, for test or execution pourposes:

```
# for execution pourposes of the exercise:
s = "azcbobobegghakl"
print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + anallize( s )
```

The great piece of this job started by: *[spacegame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2921962/spacegame)* and attended by Mr. *[Tim Petters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705542/tim-peters)*, is in the use of the native str methods and the reusability of the code.

The answer is:

Longest substring in alphabetical order is: **ccl**

Answer (score 1):

In Python character comparison is easy compared to java script where the ASCII values have to be compared. According to python

a>b gives a Boolean False and b>a gives a Boolean True

Using this the longest sub string in alphabetical order can be found by using the following algorithm :

```
def comp(a,b):
    if a<=b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
s = raw_input("Enter the required sting: ")
final = []
nIndex = 0
temp = []
for i in range(nIndex, len(s)-1):
    res = comp(s[i], s[i+1])
    if res == True:       
           if temp == []:
           #print i
               temp.append(s[i])
               temp.append(s[i+1])
           else:
               temp.append(s[i+1])
       final.append(temp)
        else:
       if temp == []:
        #print i
        temp.append(s[i])
       final.append(temp)
       temp = []
lengths = []
for el in final:
    lengths.append(len(el))
print lengths
print final
lngStr = ''.join(final[lengths.index(max(lengths))])
print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + lngStr
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list and max function to reduce the code drastically.

```
actual_string = 'azcbobobegghakl'
strlist = []
i = 0
while i < len(actual_string)-1:
    substr = ''
    while actial_string[i + 1] > actual_string[i] :
        substr += actual_string[i]
        i += 1
        if i > len(actual_string)-2:
            break
    substr += actual-string[i]
    i += 1
    strlist.append(subst)
print(max(strlist, key=len))
```

Comment: Algorithm works great.  Only comment is that you want to find matches where "a" follows "a", etc.  Therefore, you want 

while actual_string[i + 1] >= actual_string [i]

Greater than, or EQUAL TO, the previous letter

Answer (score 1):

Wow, some really impressing code snippets here...
I want to add my solution, as I think it's quite clean:

```
s = 'cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar'

res = ''
tmp = ''

for i in range(len(s)):
    tmp += s[i]
    if len(tmp) > len(res):
        res = tmp
    if i > len(s)-2:
        break
    if s[i] > s[i+1]:
        tmp = ''

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: {}".format(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using a library, but using a function `ord()` which returns ascii value for a character.
Assumption: input will be in lowercase, and no special characters are used

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

longest = ''

for i in range(len(s)):
    temp_longest=s[i]

    for j in range(i+1,len(s)):

        if ord(s[i])<=ord(s[j]):
            temp_longest+=s[j]
            i+=1
        else:
            break

    if len(temp_longest)>len(longest):
        longest = temp_longest

print(longest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different implementation, building up a list of all substrings in alphabetical order and returning the longest one:

```
def longest_substring(s):
    in_orders = ['' for i in range(len(s))]
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if (i == len(s) - 1 and s[i] >= s[i - 1]) or s[i] <= s[i + 1]:
            in_orders[index] += s[i]
        else:
            in_orders[index] += s[i]
            index += 1
    return max(in_orders, key=len)
```

Comment: Please give some comments or explanation on how the if condition works

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "azcbobobegghakl"
ls = ""
for i in range(0, len(s)-1):
    b = ""
    ss = ""
    j = 2
    while j < len(s):
        ss = s[i:i+j]
        b = sorted(ss)
        str1 = ''.join(b)
        j += 1
        if str1 == ss:
            ks = ss
        else:
            break
    if len(ks) > len(ls):
        ls = ks
print("The Longest substring in alphabetical order is "+ls)
```

Comment: It would be better to add some comments to explain the answer or use meaningful names for variables to make the code readable.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

```
s = 'cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar'

lstring = s[0]
slen = 1

for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i,len(s)-1):
            if s[j+1] >= s[j]:
                    if (j+1)-i+1 > slen:
                        lstring = s[i:(j+1)+1]
                        slen = (j+1)-i+1
            else:
                        break

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + lstring)
```

**Output:** Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ccl

Answer (score 0):

```
input_str = "cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar"
length = len(input_str) # length of the input string
iter = 0
result_str = '' # contains latest processed sub string
longest = '' # contains longest sub string alphabetic order 
while length > 1: # loop till all char processed from string
    count = 1
    key = input_str[iter] #set last checked char as key 
    result_str += key # start of the new sub string
    for i in range(iter+1, len(input_str)): # discard processed char to set new range
      length -= 1
      if(key <= input_str[i]): # check the char is in alphabetic order 
        key = input_str[i]
        result_str += key # concatenate the char to result_str
        count += 1
      else:
        if(len(longest) < len(result_str)): # check result and longest str length
          longest = result_str # if yes set longest to result
        result_str = '' # re initiate result_str for new sub string
        iter += count # update iter value to point the index of last processed char
        break

    if length is 1: # check for the last iteration of while loop
        if(len(longest) < len(result_str)):
          longest = result_str

print(longest);
```

Comment: Hi!  Could you please clarify your answer to include an English explanation of how it solves the problem?  Generally code-only answers are not actually considered answers on Stack Overflow, or at the very least are discouraged.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## finding the longest substring in alphabetical order in Python

in python shell `'a' < 'b' or 'a' <= 'a' is True`

```
result = ''
temp = ''
for char in s:
    if (not temp or temp[-1] <= char):
        temp += char
    elif (temp[-1] > char):
        if (len(result) < len(temp)):
            result = temp
        temp = char
    
if (len(temp) > len(result)):
    result = temp
    
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is:', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=input()
temp=s[0]
output=s[0]
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i]<=s[i+1]:
        temp=temp+s[i+1]
        if len(temp)>len(output):
            output=temp           
    else:
        temp=s[i+1]

print('Longest substring in alphabetic order is:' + output)
```

Comment: try explaining the answer rather than giving the code snippet. hop it will help community to gain insights of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar question on one of the tests on EDX online something. Spent 20 minutes brainstorming and couldn't find solution. But the answer got to me. And it is very simple. The thing that stopped me on other solutions - the cursor should not stop or have unique value so to say if we have the edx string s = 'azcbobobegghakl' it should output - 'beggh' not 'begh'(unique set) or 'kl'(as per the longest identical to alphabet string). Here is my answer and it works

```
n=0
for i in range(1,len(s)):
    if s[n:i]==''.join(sorted(s[n:i])):
        longest_try=s[n:i]
    else:
        n+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, input is in mixed characters like "Hello" or "HelloWorld"

**Condition 1:**order determination is case insensitive, i.e. the string "Ab" is considered to be in alphabetical order.

**Condition 2:**You can assume that the input will not have a string where the number of possible consecutive sub-strings in alphabetical order is 0. i.e. the input will not have a string like " zxec ".

```
   string ="HelloWorld"
    s=string.lower()
    r = ''
    c = ''
    last=''
    for char in s:
        if (c == ''):
            c = char
        elif (c[-1] <= char):
            c += char
        elif (c[-1] > char):
            if (len(r) < len(c)):
                r = c
                c = char
            else:
                c = char
    if (len(c) > len(r)):
        r = c
    for i in r:
        if i in string:
            last=last+i
        else:
            last=last+i.upper()
    if len(r)==1:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(last)
```

***Out:elloW***

Answer (score 0):

````
```python
s = "cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar"  # change this to any word
word, temp = "", s[0]  # temp = s[0] for fence post problem
for i in range(1, len(s)):  # starting from 1 not zero because we already add first char
    x = temp[-1]  # last word in var temp
    y = s[i]  # index in for-loop
    if x <= y:
        temp += s[i]
    elif x > y:
        if len(temp) > len(word):  #storing longest substring so we can use temp for make another substring
            word = temp
        temp = s[i]  #reseting var temp with last char in loop
    if len(temp) > len(word):
        word = temp
print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is:", word)
```
````

My code store longest substring at the moment in variable temp, then compare every string index in for-loop with last char in temp (temp[-1]) if index higher or same with (temp[-1]) then add that char from index in temp. If index lower than (temp[-1]) checking variable word and temp which one have longest substring, after that reset variable temp so we can make another substring until last char in strings.

Comment: Please be more elaborate in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'cyqfjhcclkbxpbojgkar'
long_sub = '' #longest substring
temp = '' # temporarily hold current substr
if len(s) == 1: # if only one character
    long_sub = s
else:
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        index = i
        temp = s[index]
        while index < len(s) - 1: 
            if s[index] <= s[index + 1]:
                temp += s[index + 1]
            else:
                break
            index += 1
        if len(temp) > len(long_sub):
            long_sub = temp
        temp = ''
print(long_sub)
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way:

```
s = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
count = 0
maxcount = 0
result = 0
for char in range(len(s)-1):
    if(s[char]<=s[char+1]):
       count += 1        
    if(count > maxcount):
           maxcount = count
           result = char + 1

    else:

        count = 0
startposition = result - maxcount
print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ", s[startposition:result+1])
```

Comment: Tried this. Please enter a sentence: sentententensebenz
Longest substring in alphabetical order is:  ent                                 which is wrong. Longest substrong here is "benz" !