# Finding longest substring in alphabetical order

Tags: python, recursion

**EDIT**: I am aware that a question with similar task was already asked in SO but I'm interested to find out the problem in this specific piece of code. I am also aware that this problem can be solved without using recursion.

The task is to write a program which will find (and print) the longest sub-string in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. If more than 1 equally long sequences were found, then the first one should be printed. For example, the output for a string `abczabcd` will be `abcz`.

I have solved this problem with recursion which seemed to pass my manual tests. However when I run an automated tests set which generate random strings, I have noticed that in some cases, the output is incorrect. For example:

if `s = 'hixwluvyhzzzdgd'`, the output is `hix` instead of `luvy`

if `s = 'eseoojlsuai'`, the output is `eoo` instead of `jlsu`

if `s = 'drurotsxjehlwfwgygygxz'`, the output is `dru` instead of `ehlw`

After some time struggling, I couldn't figure out what is so special about these strings that causes the bug.

This is my code:

```
pos = 0
maxLen = 0
startPos = 0
endPos = 0


def last_pos(pos):
    if pos < (len(s) - 1):
        if s[pos + 1] >= s[pos]:
            pos += 1
            if pos == len(s)-1:
                return len(s)
            else:
                return last_pos(pos)
        return pos


for i in range(len(s)):
    if last_pos(i+1) != None:
        diff = last_pos(i) - i
    if diff - 1 > maxLen:
        maxLen = diff
        startPos = i
        endPos = startPos + diff

print s[startPos:endPos+1]
```

Comment: The `homework` tag is now deprecated... do you need recursion? There's plenty of "find the longest in-order substrings from a string" going around at the moment...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for pointing that out. And to your question, no, I don't need it to be recursion but I wanted to try this way. I wonder why it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the longest substring in alphabetical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601903/find-the-longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: `diff` should be `last_pos(i) - i + 1`. And why do you compare `maxLen` with `diff - 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things to improve in your code but making minimum changes so as to make it work. The problem is you should have `if last_pos(i) != None:` in your `for` loop (`i` instead of `i+1`) and you should compare `diff` (not `diff - 1`) against `maxLen`. Please read other answers to learn how to do it better.

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if last_pos(i) != None:
        diff = last_pos(i) - i + 1
    if diff > maxLen:
        maxLen = diff
        startPos = i
        endPos = startPos + diff - 1
```

Comment: Yes! You are right about the `diff - 1 > maxLen` comparison being wrong. It forgot to change it after playing with the code. BTW, you can delete the `+1` and `-1` and the result will not change.

Comment: yes but just for making out the sense of what they are, I kept `+1` and `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Here. This does what you want. One pass, no need for recursion.

```
def find_longest_substring_in_alphabetical_order(s):
    groups = []
    cur_longest = ''
    prev_char = ''
    for c in s.lower():
        if prev_char and c < prev_char:
            groups.append(cur_longest)
            cur_longest = c
        else:
            cur_longest += c
        prev_char = c
    return max(groups, key=len) if groups else s
```

Using it:

```
>>> find_longest_substring_in_alphabetical_order('hixwluvyhzzzdgd')
'luvy'
>>> find_longest_substring_in_alphabetical_order('eseoojlsuai')
'jlsu'
>>> find_longest_substring_in_alphabetical_order('drurotsxjehlwfwgygygxz')
'ehlw'
```

**Note:** It will probably break on strange characters, has only been tested with the inputs you suggested. Since this is a "homework" question, I will leave you with the solution as is, though there is still some optimization to be done, I wanted to leave it a little bit understandable.

Comment: η-reduction: instead of `lambda x: len(x)`, just write `len`.

Comment: @GarethRees You are right, I am surprised I didn't notice that one. Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, this fails when string is 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'. The error occurs because the groups is empty

Comment: @Rohit You are Correct! Good find, solution is to simply return `s` if there are no groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `for` loops, slicing and `sorted`. If the string is not all lower-case then you can convert the sub-strings to lower-case before comparing using `str.lower`:

```
def solve(strs):
  maxx = ''
  for i in xrange(len(strs)):
      for j in xrange(i+1, len(strs)):
          s = strs[i:j+1]
          if ''.join(sorted(s)) == s:
              maxx = max(maxx, s, key=len)
          else:
              break
  return maxx
```

**Output:**

```
>>> solve('hixwluvyhzzzdgd')
'luvy'
>>> solve('eseoojlsuai')
'jlsu'
>>> solve('drurotsxjehlwfwgygygxz')
'ehlw'
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a powerful builtin package [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and a wonderful function within [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

An intuitive use of the Key function can give immense mileage.

In this particular case, you just have to keep a track of order change and group the sequence accordingly. The only exception is the boundary case which you have to handle separately

**Code**

```
def find_long_cons_sub(s):
    class Key(object):
        '''
        The Key function returns 
            1: For Increasing Sequence
            0: For Decreasing Sequence
        '''
        def __init__(self):
            self.last_char = None
        def __call__(self, char):
            resp = True
            if self.last_char:
                resp = self.last_char < char
            self.last_char = char
            return resp
    def find_substring(groups):
        '''
        The Boundary Case is when an increasing sequence
        starts just after the Decresing Sequence. This causes
        the first character to be in the previous group.
        If you do not want to handle the Boundary Case
        seperately, you have to mak the Key function a bit 
        complicated to flag the start of increasing sequence'''
        yield next(groups)
        try:
            while True:
                yield next(groups)[-1:] + next(groups)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    groups = (list(g) for k, g in groupby(s, key = Key()) if k)
    #Just determine the maximum sequence based on length
    return ''.join(max(find_substring(groups), key = len))
```

**Result**

```
>>> find_long_cons_sub('drurotsxjehlwfwgygygxz')
'ehlw'
>>> find_long_cons_sub('eseoojlsuai')
'jlsu'
>>> find_long_cons_sub('hixwluvyhzzzdgd')
'luvy'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy.

**Code :**

```
s = 'hixwluvyhzzzdgd' 
r,p,t = '','',''
for c in s:
    if p <= c:
        t += c
        p = c
    else:
        if len(t) > len(r):
            r = t
        t,p = c,c
if len(t) > len(r):
    r = t
print 'Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + r
```

**Output :**

```
Longest substring in alphabetical order which appeared first: luvy
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single pass solution with a fast loop.  It reads each character only once.  Inside the loop operations are limited to

- 1 string comparison (1 char x 1 char)
- 1 integer increment
- 2 integer subtractions
- 1 integer comparison
- 1 to 3 integer assignments
- 1 string assignment

No containers are used.  No function calls are made.  The empty string is handled without special-case code.  All character codes, including chr(0), are properly handled. If there is a tie for the longest alphabetical substring, the function returns the first winning substring it encountered. Case is ignored for purposes of alphabetization, but case is preserved in the output substring.

```
def longest_alphabetical_substring(string):
    start, end = 0, 0     # range of current alphabetical string
    START, END = 0, 0     # range of longest alphabetical string yet found
    prev = chr(0)         # previous character

    for char in string.lower():   # scan string ignoring case
        if char < prev:       # is character out of alphabetical order?
            start = end       #     if so, start a new substring 
        end += 1              # either way, increment substring length 

        if end - start > END - START:  # found new longest?  
            START, END = start, end    #     if so, update longest 
        prev = char                    # remember previous character

    return string[START : END]   # return longest alphabetical substring
```

### **Result**

```
>>> longest_alphabetical_substring('drurotsxjehlwfwgygygxz')
'ehlw'
>>> longest_alphabetical_substring('eseoojlsuai')
'jlsu'
>>> longest_alphabetical_substring('hixwluvyhzzzdgd')
'luvy'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

a lot more looping, but it gets the job done

```
s = raw_input("Enter string")
fin=""
s_pos =0
while s_pos < len(s):
    n=1
    lng=" "
    for c in s[s_pos:]:
        if c >= lng[n-1]:
            lng+=c
            n+=1
        else :
            break
    if len(lng) > len(fin):
        fin= lng`enter code here`
    s_pos+=1    
print "Longest string: " + fin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_longest_order():
`enter code here`arr = []
`enter code here`now_long = ''
    prev_char = ''
    for char in s.lower():
        if prev_char and char < prev_char:
            arr.append(now_long)
            now_long = char
        else:
            now_long += char
        prev_char = char
    if len(now_long) == len(s):
        return now_long
    else:   
        return max(arr, key=len)

def main():
    print 'Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + find_longest_order()

main()
```

Comment: supports testcase 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy to understand:

```
s = "abcbcd"    #The original string

l = len(s)    #The length of the original string

maxlenstr = s[0]    #maximum length sub-string, taking the first letter of original string as value.

curlenstr = s[0]    #current length sub-string, taking the first letter of original string as value.

for i in range(1,l):    #in range, the l is not counted. 

    if s[i] >= s[i-1]:    #If current letter is greater or equal to previous letter,
        curlenstr += s[i] #add the current letter to current length sub-string
    else:        
        curlenstr = s[i]  #otherwise, take the current letter as current length sub-string

    if len(curlenstr) > len(maxlenstr): #if current cub-string's length is greater than max one,
            maxlenstr = curlenstr;      #take current one as max one.

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is:", maxlenstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input("insert some string: ")
start = 0
end = 0
temp = ""
while end+1 <len(s):
    while end+1 <len(s) and s[end+1] >= s[end]:
        end += 1
    if len(s[start:end+1]) > len(temp):
        temp = s[start:end+1]
    end +=1
    start = end
print("longest ordered part is: "+temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is problem set question for CS6.00.1x on EDX. Here is what I came up with.

```
s = raw_input("Enter the string: ")
longest_sub = ""
last_longest = ""
for i in range(len(s)):
    if len(last_longest) > 0:
        if last_longest[-1] <= s[i]:
            last_longest += s[i]
        else:
            last_longest = s[i]
    else:
        last_longest = s[i]
    if len(last_longest) > len(longest_sub):
        longest_sub = last_longest
print(longest_sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution

```
def longest_sorted_string(s):
    max_string = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
            string = s[i:j]
            arr = list(string)
            if sorted(string) == arr and len(max_string) < len(string):
                max_string = string
    return max_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is from Edx course: 
till this question, we haven't taught anything about strings and their advanced operations in python
So, I would simply go through the looping and conditional statements

```
string =""             #taking a plain string to represent the then generated string
present =""             #the present/current longest string
for i in range(len(s)): #not len(s)-1 because that totally skips last value
    j = i+1            
    if j>= len(s):    
        j=i           #using s[i+1] simply throws an error of not having index
    if s[i] <= s[j]:  #comparing the now and next value
        string += s[i] #concatinating string if above condition is satisied
    elif len(string) != 0 and s[i] > s[j]: #don't want to lose the last value
        string += s[i] #now since s[i] > s[j] #last one will be printed
        if len(string) > len(present): #1 > 0 so from there we get to store many values
            present = string #swapping to largest string
        string = ""
    if len(string) > len(present): #to swap from if statement
        present = string
if present == s[len(s)-1]: #if no alphabet is in order then first one is to be the output
    present = s[0]
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is:' + present)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Abhijit about the power of `itertools.groupby()` but I took  a simpler approach to (ab)using it and avoided the boundary case problems:

```
from itertools import groupby

LENGTH, LETTERS = 0, 1

def longest_sorted(string):
    longest_length, longest_letters = 0, []
    key, previous_letter = 0, chr(0)

    def keyfunc(letter):
        nonlocal key, previous_letter
        if letter < previous_letter:
            key += 1

        previous_letter = letter
        return key

    for _, group in groupby(string, keyfunc):
        letters = list(group)
        length = len(letters)

        if length > longest_length:
            longest_length, longest_letters = length, letters

    return ''.join(longest_letters)

print(longest_sorted('hixwluvyhzzzdgd'))
print(longest_sorted('eseoojlsuai'))
print(longest_sorted('drurotsxjehlwfwgygygxz'))
print(longest_sorted('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
luvy
jlsu
ehlw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl' 

i=1
subs=s[0]
subs2=s[0]
while(i<len(s)):
    j=i
    while(j<len(s)):
        if(s[j]>=s[j-1]):
            subs+=s[j]
            j+=1 
        else:
            subs=subs.replace(subs[:len(subs)],s[i])   
            break

        if(len(subs)>len(subs2)):
            subs2=subs2.replace(subs2[:len(subs2)], subs[:len(subs)])
    subs=subs.replace(subs[:len(subs)],s[i])
    i+=1
print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is:",subs2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A good answer describes what a code snippet is doing, why it is important, etc. Just giving a segment of code does not contribute to the goal of the site for future readers to find this answer very helpful

Answer (score -1):

```
s = 'gkuencgybsbezzilbfg'
x = s.lower()
y = ''
z = [] #creating an empty listing which will get filled

for i in range(0,len(x)):
    if i == len(x)-1:
       y = y + str(x[i])
       z.append(y)
       break 
    a = x[i] <= x[i+1]
    if a == True:
        y = y + str(x[i])
    else: 
        y = y + str(x[i])
        z.append(y)  # fill the list 
        y = ''
# search of 1st longest string        
L = len(max(z,key=len))      # key=len takes length in consideration 
for i in range(0,len(z)):
    a = len(z[i])
    if a == L:   
        print 'Longest substring in alphabetical order is:' + str(z[i])
        break
```

Comment: Please explain how to fix the problem, rather than posting the fixed code.

Answer (score -1):

```
first_seq=s[0]
break_seq=s[0]
current = s[0]
for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
    if s[i]<=s[i+1]:
        first_seq = first_seq + s[i+1]
        if len(first_seq) > len(current):
            current = first_seq
    else:
        first_seq = s[i+1]
        break_seq = first_seq
print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ", current)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add an explanation of how your code works and solves the problem.