# How can I find the longest ascending substring (or tied substrings)?

Tags: python

How to define a recurion-style function **findmax** which works like:

```
findmax('abc')-->['abc']
findmax('afz')-->['afz']
findmax('cba')-->['c','b','a']
findmax('zfa')-->['z','f','a']
findmax('abczabc')-->['abcz']
findmax('abcabc')-->['abc','abc']
```

the function only reveives one or more a-z chars. And return all the longest substring that the chars rank in ascending order.

Why I ask this question? Becasuse my intuition tells me there must be an elegant recusion-style solution. But saddly, I can't work it out.

please take a look at the terrible solution I wrote:

```
def findmax(s):
    res=[]
    string=s[0]
    end=len(s)
    for i in range(1,end):
        if ord(s[i-1])<=ord(s[i]):
            string+=s[i]
            if i==end-1:
                res.append(string)                
        else:
            res.append(string)
            string=s[i]
            if i==end-1:
                res.append(string)
    fin=[]
    maxNum=0
    for r in res:
        size=len(r)
        if size>maxNum:
            maxNum=size
            fin=[]
            fin.append(r)
        elif size==maxNum:
            fin.append(r)                    
    return fin
```

Comment: `findmax('zfa')-->['z','f','c']` Whats going on here?

Comment: There's nothing in this problem that suggests recursion would be a useful strategy. Why would you use recursion here?

Comment: @Games I'm guessing because they're not ascending, but there's an apparent inconsistency between `abczabc` and `abcabc`

Comment: @JonClements: I'm guessing that's because in `abcabc` the longest ascending substring is tied for length 3

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ahh yes... good spot :)

Comment: I just [answered a similar question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19618657/1561176)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding longest substring in alphabetical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618533/finding-longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: @Games Brainiac sorry, when I wrongly pasted the data. Fixed.

Comment: @Pythoner If you _really_ want a recursive solution, I'm working on that right now, but you're going to have to wait a little longer.

Comment: @Games Brainiac thank you in advance! These days I am studying Scheme. And I rewrote a lot of basic standard Functions with the most basic elements in Scheme. I really feel that recursion is a very powful and simple solution for many situations. So...

Comment: @David Robinson Thanks. But I think it shows no recursion-style solutions. I don't want to miss an possible elegant recusion-style answer and I really can't work it out. So I came here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a recursive solution. This function is purely recursive, no for loops or rather, no looping at all:

```
def find_max(s):
    _ret = []

    def string_iter(concat, compare):

        def appender():
            if len(concat) >= len(_ret[-1]):
                if len(concat) > len(_ret[-1]):
                    while _ret:
                        _ret.pop()
                _ret.append(concat)

        if len(compare) == 0:
            if len(_ret) != 0:
                appender()
            else:
                _ret.append(concat)
            return

        if concat[-1] < compare[0]:
            concat += compare[0]
            string_iter(concat, compare[1:])
        else:
            if len(_ret) != 0:
                appender()
            else:
                _ret.append(concat)
            string_iter(compare[0], compare[1:])

    string_iter(s[0], s[1:])

    return _ret

print find_max('abc')      # -->['abc']
print find_max('afz')      # -->['afz']
print find_max('cba')      # -->['c','b','a']
print find_max('zfa')      # -->['z','f','a']
print find_max('abczabc')  # --> ['abcz']
print find_max('abcabcpaidfbkjabdsfilabdfkabldfjadf')   # --> ['abcp', 'abdfk']
```

Comment: Hey,the statement `while ret:` should be `while _ret:`?

Comment: Add , thank you again..I prefer 'no import' style..so choose yours

Comment: @Pythoner, oops, that's my fault. I was trying to fix the original code (it returned the wrong value for `find_max('cbad')`), and I accidentally left out the underscore.

Comment: @Kevin never mind , it is easy to find. And the first version of this answer is almost what I want despite of the incorrect return value.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a recursion-flavored function. I don't know if it's much more elegant, but I know it is less effective and much more limited than imperative style (recursion limit and tail calls) :

```
from collections import defaultdict

'''
    Return the "biggest" key (assuming keys are int).
    Should've used a ordered set instead of a dict
'''
def maxkey(dictio):
    return max ([ int(k) for k in dictio.keys() ])

'''
    Recursion-style of findmax. Notice the call to the same input string minus the first element,
    which indicate that the recursion isn't really much more efficient than imperative style.
    Also we have to take the maximum recursion limit into account (which should be attained in practice.)
'''
def findmax( input_string , tempbuffer = defaultdict(list), temp = '' ):

    # End of the recursion
    if len(input_string) == 0:
        tempbuffer[len(temp)].append(temp)          # add last element
        output = tempbuffer[maxkey(tempbuffer)]     # return the set of longest elements
        tempbuffer.clear()                          # pesky little mutable objects ...
        return output

    # Still elements in the input string
    else:
        first_char = input_string[0]

        # still ascending : buffering
        if len(temp) == 0 or first_char > temp[-1]:
            temp   = temp + first_char
        # new string : store the old one
        else:
            tempbuffer[len(temp)].append(temp)
            temp   = first_char

        # Recursion call on the 'tail' of the input string, one character at a time
        return findmax( input_string[1:],tempbuffer, temp)




if __name__ == '__main__' :

    print findmax('abczabc')

    print findmax('abcabd')
```

Comment: +1 for "pesky little mutable objects". However, putting docstrings above the function definition confused me for a second.

Comment: I know it's not PEP-257 compliant, but I can't help it since I come from C and C++ :p

Comment: thanks ,especially for  `defaultdict(list)` and `tempbuffer.clear() `.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for recursion at all.

```
def findmax(s):
    matches = []
    current = [s[0]]
    for index, character in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if character >= s[index]:
            current.append(character)
        else:
            matches.append(current)
            current = [character]
    matches.append(current)
    maxlen = len(max(matches, key=len))
    return ["".join(match) for match in matches if len(match)==maxlen]
```

Test cases:

```
>>> findmax('abc')
['abc']
>>> findmax('afz')
['afz']
>>> findmax('cba')
['c', 'b', 'a']
>>> findmax('zfa')
['z', 'f', 'a']
>>> findmax('abczabc')
['abcz']
>>> findmax('abcabc')
['abc', 'abc']
```

[Explanation can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562798/20670) (with a slightly modified version of this code).

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [my solution to a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618657/1561176):

```
import string

def findmax(s):
    groups = []
    cur_longest = ''
    prev_char = ''
    for c in map(string.lower, s):
        if prev_char and c < prev_char:
            groups.append(cur_longest)
            cur_longest = c
        else:
            cur_longest += c
        prev_char = c
    groups.append(cur_longest)
    length = max([len(g) for g in groups])
    return [group for group in groups if len(group) == length]
```

Using it:

```
>>> findmax('abc') # expect: ['abc']
['abc']
>>> findmax('afz') # expect: ['afz']
['afz']
>>> findmax('cba') # expect: ['c','b','a']
['c', 'b', 'a']
>>> findmax('zfa') # expect: ['z','f','a']
['z', 'f', 'a']
>>> findmax('abczabc') # expect: ['abcz']
['abcz']
>>> findmax('abcabc') # expect: ['abc','abc']
['abc', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

After studying the two answers from georgesl and Games Brainiac, I got a more satisfied solution combining both advantages of them.

Both of them are well designed in structure.

I think the advantage of georgesl's is : the design of  `tempbuffer` dict object,while the one of Games Brainiac's is : the design of `closure`.

Although it is less effective , I am still very happy that there does exists a simple and elegant solution.

So, here I'd like to share :

```
from collections import defaultdict

def findmax(s):
    buf=defaultdict(list)
    def recur(s,mbr):
        if s=='':
            buf[len(mbr)].append(mbr)
            return buf[max(buf)]
        else:
            head=s[0]
            if mbr=='' or mbr[-1]<head:
                mbr=mbr+head
            else:
                buf[len(mbr)].append(mbr)
                mbr=head
            return recur(s[1:],mbr)
    return recur(s,'')

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print 'abc',findmax('abc')
    print 'afz',findmax('afz') 
    print 'abcabcda',findmax('abcabcda')
    print 'abczabcdabcd',findmax('abczabcdabcd')               
    print 'zfa',findmax('zfa')
    print 'zfa',findmax('zfa')
```

and here is the result:

```
>>> 
abc ['abc']
afz ['afz']
abcabcda ['abcd']
abczabcdabcd ['abcz', 'abcd', 'abcd']
zfa ['z', 'f', 'a']
zfa ['z', 'f', 'a']
```