# Tracing recursive function in paper

Tags: python, recursion, language-agnostic

I am learning recursion nowadays and as the saying goes, the best way to get proficient in recursion is to practice as much as possible. I have a habit of tracing the program in paper (I guess all of us had at some point).

For example, If I had a function like printing a number from 1 to 10:

```
def print_n():
    for i in range(1,11):
        print i
```

I would trace like:

```
i
.......
1
2
3
4
... and so on
```

But when I am practicing with recursion, I am finding hard time tracing the program in paper. Can somebody recommend with example a best way to trace recursive function in paper?
You can use the following Fibonacci (again!!!) to illustrate your example or you might surprise the readership.

```
#RECURSIVE FUNCTION TO RETURN Nth FIBONACCI NUMBER
def fib(n):
    if n is 0 or n is 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: Actually, the best way to get proficient at recursion is to get proficient at recursion.

Comment: I think I am reading so much about recursion these days that the joke you just told is old.

Comment: http://www.emunix.emich.edu/~haynes/Papers/Recursion/recursion.html

Comment: @gtgaxiola: nice link

Comment: I'm writing one that involves a debugger. Hope you can wait to see it.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Posted the answer, and a link to a good website, I hope you like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just throwing this answer in here. I used debuggers a lot, in my development, and they've helped me a lot too. So, I recommend this, because they can often be more helpful, than just printing out strings on the recursion depth.

What I would do when I wanted to trace a recursive function (just wrote a recursive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658335/how-can-i-find-the-longest-ascending-substring-or-tied-substrings/19659371#19659371)), is that I'd set break points as specific points.

Ideally, most debuggers will allow you to see a list of values that are relevant to the current scope, and allow you to `step into` a function call to see how it runs.

What I usually do, is create a watchlist of the variables that are important to me. What I do then, is create a diagram of function calls. Very similar to the diagrams created on this website, for [example](http://goo.gl/sKQEhf).

[image]

My best way to deal with recursion has been to use a debugger bundled with pen and paper. Or if your debugger supports static watchlists, then you don't even need to do that at times. However, I would like to say that at the beginning, its best to sketch things out with pen and paper, since it gives you a better understanding overall of how your program works. Sometimes, people just use recursion and expect the computer to solve the problem for them, and thats awesome, however, its imperative, that you *know* how your recursion works, and for that (for a beginner) pen and paper are your best tools.

Comment: Checked the web-link! Great job! Really liked it.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades If you could wait just a little longer, I'll show you some of my diagrams.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Take a look at the answer now, should make things clearer. I did not expand on 3, because there was no need to, as 4 would expand to 3 anyways :P

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Glad you liked it, I drew that with a graphics tablet.

Comment: Which debugger are you using for Python 3?

Comment: @Abrar I am using the PyCharm debugger.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I would probably put this down on paper, `fib(5)` shown below:

```
                                          fib(5)
                       fib(4)               +                  fib(3)
              fib(3)     +      fib(2)      +         fib(2)     +   fib(1)   
     fib(2)     + fib(1) + fib(1) + fib(0)  +    fib(1) + fib(0) +     1
fib(1) + fib(0) +   1    +   1    +   1     +      1    +   1    +     1
  1    +   1    +   1    +   1    +   1     +      1    +   1    +     1
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Great visual representation

Answer (score 4):

Let the computer do the heavy lifting for you! By adding a few lines you can watch how the function dives in recursively:

```
def fib(n,depth=0):
    print ''.join(["*"]*depth), n

    if n is 0 or n is 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1,depth+1) + fib(n-2,depth+1)

fib(5)
```

Gives:

```
 5
* 4
** 3
*** 2
**** 1
**** 0
*** 1
** 2
*** 1
*** 0
* 3
** 2
*** 1
*** 0
** 1
```

Note that we are tracking the depth in addition to `n` now. In this case it's easy to see how `depth` and `n` are related, but in other cases it might not be so obvious so this exercise is not completely academic. We print out a visual representation of `depth` by the line `''.join(["*"]*depth)` which simply creates a string of `*`'s the same size of depth.

Comment: thanks for the clever use of letting program do the heavy-lifting.

Answer (score 4):

It would go like this:

```
fib(3)
 n=3 so return fib(2) + fib(1)

So now we need fib(2) and fib (1)

   fib(2)
    n =2 so return fib(1)+fib(0)
    fib (1)
     n=1 so return 1

    fib (0) 
     n=0 so return 1

    Now we can have fib(2) return 1+1 = 2. We still need to do fib(1) to return the value of fib(3)

    fib(1)
     n=1 so return 1

Now we can return fib(3)'s value of 2+1=3
```