# How to provide the longest alphabetical sequence in a text string which is unsorted?

Tags: java

I have been trying to use Java to determine the longest alphabetical substring in an unsorted text string. For example, a text string of 'gxabchaxc' would output the following result of 'abch'.
I have 8 million records which I need to be identify longest alpha substring. Would anyone have any Java experience which can be applied to my existing problem.  I have attempted some code below.  However, I do not know how to get the longest alphabetical substring.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
string = "gxabchaxc";
//This will determine the length of the string
String t = "";
int i;
int n = 0;
for (i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char ch = string.charAt(i);
    t += " ";
    n = ch - 'a' + 1;
    t += String.valueOf(n);
 
}
System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the longest substring in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601903/find-the-longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order)

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack to keep track of the alphabetical substring. See [Find the longest substring in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601903/find-the-longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order) (which is in Python, but can be converted to Java). Many other options exist.